# Basic Sklearn: How to Pass Scoring Function to Fit Method

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using `sklearn` to do some machine learning.  I often use `GridSearchCV` to explore hyperparameters and perform cross-validation.  Using this, I can specify a `scoring` function, like this:

```
scores = -cross_val_score(svr, X, Y, cv=10, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

However, I want to train my `SVR` model using mean squared error.  Unfortunately, there's no `scoring` parameter in either the constructor for `SVR` or the `fit` method.

How should I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: So you actually want a custom objective function or loss function, not scoring. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698160/python-svm-function-with-huber-loss) and [this scikit issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1701)

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `Pipeline` to do it. You can create list of pipelines including `SVR` model (and others if you want). Then, you can apply `GridSearchCV` where putting `pipeline` in as your argument.

Here, you can add `params_grid` where searching space can be defined as `pipelinename__paramname` (double underscore in between). For example, I have pipeline name `svr` and I want to search on parameter `C`, I can put the key in my parameter dictionary as `svr__C`.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR

c_range = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
pipeline = Pipeline([('svr', SVR())])
params_grid = {'svr__C': c_range}
# grid search with 3-fold cross validation
gridsearch_model = GridSearchCV(pipeline, params_grid, 
                                cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

Then, you can do the same procedure by fitting training data and find best score and parameters

```
gridsearch_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(gridsearch_model.best_params_, gridsearch_model.best_score_)
```

You can also use `cross_val_score` to find the score:

```
cross_val_score(gridsearch_model, X_train, y_train, 
                cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  So when you call `gridsearch_model.fit(X_train, y_train)`, is that training the model with `neg_mean_squared_error`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so!

Comment: Great!  So there's no general scoring function to pass into fit?  I don't see it in any of the docs for `LinearRegression`, `svm.SVR`, etc.  Seems crazy!  Don't think I should have to do GridSearchCV just to say how I want the loss calculated...

Comment: Ah, I see. So you just want to calculate `neg_mean_squared_error `. I guess `cross_val_score` also have it implemented? Let me check quickly